# dirname strange behavior with file list & Makefile

Tags: makefile, csh, dirname

My directory :

```
$ ls *
Makefile

dir1:
file1.txt  file2.txt

dir2:
file1.txt
```

The Makefile :

```
A = $(wildcard ./dir1/*)
A += $(wildcard ./dir1/*)
B = $(dirname $(A))

print-% : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

Outputs of print rule :

```
$ make print-A
A = ./dir1/file1.txt ./dir1/file2.txt ./dir1/file1.txt ./dir1/file2.txt
$ make print-B
B =
```

I would like the `B` variable to have the list of my sub directory relative paths (`./dir1/` and `./dir2/`) why this don't work ? It is ok if there is only on file in `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the `$(dirname ...)` macro defined? `$(dir ...)` may do what you expect.